# MongoDB paginate 2 collections together on common field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I've two mongo collections - `File` and `Folder`.

Both have some common fields like `name`, `createdAt` etc. I've a `resources` API that returns a response having items from both collections, with a `type` property added. `type` can be `file` or `folder`

I want to support pagination and sorting in this list, for example sort by `createdAt`. Is it possible with `aggregation`, and how?

Moving them to a container collection is not a preferred option, as then I have to maintain the container collection on each `create/update/delete` on either of the collection.

I'm using mongoose too, if it has got any utility function for this, or a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/). Something like:

```
Folder.aggregate([
  { $project: { name: 1, createdAt: 1 } },
  { 
    $unionWith: { 
      coll: "files", pipeline: [ { $project: { name: 1, createdAt: 1 } } ]
    } 
  },
  ... // your sorting go here
])
```